# React-native error in react-native-vector-icons module/MaterialIcons

Tags: react-native

When i try to run app **react-native-vector-icons** modules gives following error.

```
    Error: While resolving module `react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons`, 
the Haste package `react-native-vector-icons` was found.
```

When i uninstall package my project works fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run this command :

   rm ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/**fixtures**/files/package.json
2. And restart packager

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I had to remove the entire fixtures folder before it would stop complaining.